# adding a value to an associative array with a foreach?

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

***Solution Found and voted on***

---

Here is my code:

```
//go through each question
foreach($file_data as $value) {
    //separate the string by pipes and place in variables
    list($title, $content, $date_posted) = explode('|', $value);

    //create an associative array for each input
    $file_data_array['title'] = $title;
    $file_data_array['content'] = $content;
    $file_data_array['date_posted'] = $date_posted;

}
```

What happens is that the assoc values keep getting erased. Is there a way I can have the value append to array? If not, how else could I do this?

Comment: Didn't let me for the first 15 minutes. My comment was a bit preemptive. . .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could append to the `$file_data_array` array using something like this :

```
foreach($file_data as $value) {
    list($title, $content, $date_posted) = explode('|', $value);
    $item = array(
        'title' => $title, 
        'content' => $content, 
        'date_posted' => $date_posted
    );
    $file_data_array[] = $item;
}
```

*(The temporary `$item` variable could be avoided, doing the declaration of the array and the affectation at the end of `$file_data_array` at the same time)*

For more informations, take a look at the following section of the manual : [**Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)

Comment: This is a really clean solution.  I'd vote it over my solution. =D

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to append associative arrays to `$file_data_array`?

If so:

```
//go through each question
foreach($file_data as $value) {
    //separate the string by pipes and place in variables
    list($title, $content, $date_posted) = explode('|', $value);

    //create an associative array for each input
    $file_data_array[] = array(
        "title" => $title,
        "content" => $content,
        "date_posted" => $date_posted,
    );

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but was second :/

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra key.

```
//go through each question
$x=0;
foreach($file_data as $value) {
    //separate the string by pipes and place in variables
    list($title, $content, $date_posted) = explode('|', $value);

    //create an associative array for each input
    $file_data_array[$x]['title'] = $title;
    $file_data_array[$x]['content'] = $content;
    $file_data_array[$x]['date_posted'] = $date_posted;
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: I can still receive that value by using `$file_data_array['title']`?

Comment: No.  But accessing the data that way is part of the problem.  You can access it with `$file_data_array[0]['title']` for the first one, `$file_data_array[1]['title']` for the 2nd, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$file_data_array = array(
     'title'=>array(),
     'content'=>array(),
     'date_posted'=>array()
);
//go through each question
foreach($file_data as $value) {
    //separate the string by pipes and place in variables
    list($title, $content, $date_posted) = explode('|', $value);

    //create an associative array for each input
    $file_data_array['title'][] = $title;
    $file_data_array['content'][] = $content;
    $file_data_array['date_posted'][] = $date_posted;

}
```

you final array would look something like:

```
$file_data_array = array(
   'title' => array ( 't1', 't2' ),
   'content' => array ( 'c1', 'c2' ),
   'date_posted' => array ( 'dp1', 'dp2' )
)
```

here is a demo of it:

http://codepad.org/jdFabrzE

Comment: I don't like that this stores all titles together, instead of storing titles, contents, and date_posted under the same key.  Matter of preference though.